# Target shows as hyperlink

Tags: html, anchor, target

I tried to create a target, but for whatever reason, the target bit the "id" links to displays the text as a link which is not not a link, if you know what I mean (it's a header; it underlines and there's that pointer arrow to cursor change, but obviously it does not link anywhere because it is itself the target). How do I make this not happen? (Page: http://www.thesimplewardrobeblog.com/post/114843804438/how-to-develop-your-personal-style)

Thanks in advance, Richie

My code is as follows

LINK:

```
<p class="subhead"><a href="#workbook" target="_self">Skip to Workbook Below</a></p>
```

TARGET:

```
<h2><a id="workbook">Your Personal Style Workbook: Six Exercises To Help You Discover Your Personal Style</a></h2>
```

Comment: I cannot understand your problem.

Comment: I cannot see the problem you describe, or this question is cleverly designed spam.

Comment: _sorry, I can't figure out how to show the code_ (O.o)

Comment: @D4V1D If you click on the webpage I've added, you'll see what I mean, I think? The "Workbook" link goes to the target headline lower down the page, but that headline is a kind of empty "link". I don't know why this happens and how I can make it not do this.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ I have a genuine question, I have no intention of spamming.

Comment: `that headline is a kind of empty "link".`? Well, why don't you put your `ID` in your `<h2>` tag instead of an`<a>` tag that has nothing to do here in this is not a hypertext link?

Comment: @D4V1D I have just tried this, but now my anchor does not skip down to the part of the page I want to send the user to. Ugh.

Comment: I can see that the `Skip to Workbook Below` link **does** skip down to the part where `<h2 id="workbook">Your Personal Style Workbook</h2>` is. I cannot understand what's your problem.

Comment: I think you forgot to close the opening a tag <a **>**

Comment: @D4V1D Weirdly, when I implemented your suggestion, the pointer had to go much higher than the actual "SKIP..." link? Then i refreshed and it now it seems to work! Thank you!

Comment: No problem! I have posted it as an answer to make it clearer for other users. Feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `ID` in your `<h2>` tag. Do not create an `<a>` tag just for that. Like so:

```
<h2 id="workbook">Your Personal Style Workbook: Six Exercises To Help You Discover Your Personal Style</h2>
```